# Keeping the value of a HTML form

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to make a simple score keeper application for a physical game, such as Scrabble.  I have two pages, one that asks for the user's name, and the other for calculating their score.  I want to display the names of the users on the second page next to their score; for example, Max: 47.  The problem is that the page only displays the names of the users once.  After somebody enters a score, they disappear.  I've tried using cookies, but they only seem to make matters worse by not displaying anything!  You can access the application, not showing the names, at ripdvd.x10.mx.  Does anyone know of a simple solution to this?

First page:

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Select Players</title>
<link rel=StyleSheet href="style.css" type="text/css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="scoregen.php">
    <p class="par">
        <label for="player1">Please type in the one of the players first name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="player1" name="player1" size="17"  maxlength="17" value="Enter Name" class="textbox" />
    </p>

    <p class="par">
        <label for="player2">Please type in another players first name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="player2" name="player2" size="17"  maxlength="17" value="Enter Name" class="textbox" />
    </p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Start Playing!" />


    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Second page:

```
$addScore1 = $_POST['addScore1'];
$addScore2 = $_POST['addScore2'];

$oldScore1 = $_POST['oldScore1'];
$oldScore2 = $_POST['oldScore2'];

$curr1=$_COOKIE["score1"]+$addScore1;
$curr2=$_COOKIE["score2"]+$addScore2;
setcookie("score1", $_COOKIE["score1"]+$addScore1, time()+3600);
setcookie("score2", $_COOKIE["score2"]+$addScore2, time()+3600);

//Reset cookies if reset button is 't', which makes it clear scores
if ($clse = t){
setcookie ("score1", "", time() - 3600);
setcookie ("score2", "", time() - 3600);
}


// Generate HTML form
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Score Add</title>
        <link rel=StyleSheet href="style.css" type="text/css">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>

    <body>
    <form method="post" action=" ">

     <p class="par">
            <label for="addScore1">Enter your score, <?php echo $player1; ?>:</label>
            <input type="text" name="addScore1" id="addScore1" class="textbox" />
            <input type="hidden" name="oldScore1" id="oldScore1" value="<?php echo $oldscore1; ?>" />
        <input type="submit" value="Add Score!" />
    </p>

    <p class="par">
        <label for="addScore2">Enter your score, <?php echo $player2; ?>:</label>
        <input type="text" name="addScore2" id="addScore2" class="textbox"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="oldScore2" id="oldScore2" value="<?php echo $oldscore2; ?>" />
            <input type="submit" value="Add Score!"/>
        </form>
    </p>

         <form method="post" action=" ">
         <input type="hidden" name="clsc" id="clsc" value="t" />
         <input type="submit" value="Clear Scores" />
         </form>
<!--Shows player and score-->
    <p class="par"><?php echo $player1;?>:<?php echo $curr1?></p>
    <p class="par"><?php echo $player2;?>:<?php echo $curr2?></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: in the second page (scoregen.php), you're not initializing `$player1` and `$player2`. I'm supposing you should get those from the `$_POST` sent from the previous page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t use cookies for this.  Start a `$_SESSION` and store the information in there then echo it out of the `$_SESSION` on the next page.

Answer (score 0):

youcan make table temporary file for all data, so you select all, and make that ajax when you use it '$_session' is one good too :D

Comment: You talking about a _temporary_ SQL table?